# How to twitter like load a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm the only one that noticed that the new version of twitter desktop even if there is no internet it still loads the main styling and then just tell that there is no internet? Well I did and now I'd like to make to a website that can be loaded even without internet, can anyone tell me how? I'm using pure HTML, CSS and js as front end and node js as a back end.

```
I currently have no idea how to do it
```

I'd like it to load ad be able to run flew scripts to generate elements on the page.

Comment: Read Web caching

Comment: Twitter is based on PWA (Progressive web app: https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps). For the first time is loads data than for the next every request is serves data from cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Progressive Web Apps, Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) are web applications that are regular web pages or websites, but can appear to the user like traditional applications or native mobile applications. The application type attempts to combine features offered by most modern browsers with the benefits of a mobile experience.

1. https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps
2. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp

Answer (score -1):

A Web cache (or HTTP cache) is an information technology for the temporary storage (caching) of Web documents, such as Web pages, images, and other types of Web multimedia, to reduce server lag. `--Wikipedia`.

The web page is already stored, when you load it loads from the cache and a function which checks for connection gives the alert of no internet connection.